# For loop not iterating over arraylist in javascript

Tags: javascript, spring, jsp, for-loop, iteration

I have an arraylist of type User which looks like:

```
console.log([User  [id=1, firstName= Sagar, lastName= Dafle, address= Address street 33 S, 3rd street, city San Jose, state California, zip 95113, title= Software Engineer], User  [id=2, firstName= Vikas, lastName= Dafle, address= Address street 33 S, 3rd street, city San Jose, state California, zip 95113, title= MBA]]);
```

Now, I wish to iterate over this list of size 2 and print the user.id and user.firstname .
However, when I do so , I get the first record printed twice as:

```
 {1,Sagar} {1,Sagar}
```

Note that the expected output is:

```
{1,Sagar} {2,Vikas}
```

My loop to iterate over the list is :

```
userlistlength = ${phone.userList.size()};
        //console.log(${phone.userList});
        console.log("userlistlength "+userlistlength); //prints 2

        if(userlistlength>0){
            document.write("User List:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;\n");

            for( var counter = 0; counter < userlistlength ; counter++){
                console.log("Counter "+counter); //prints 0 and 1
                id = '${phone.userList.get(counter).id}';
                firstname = '${phone.userList.get(counter).firstname}';
                document.write("{"+id+","+firstname+"}\n");
                document.write("\n");
            }
        }
```

Note that I receive the phone object from my spring controller as a model attribute. 
Any idea where am I going wrong ?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: What is `${}`? Some kind of server-side templating language? If yes, you cannot mix that with JS - your `counter` in `userList.get(counter)` is not what you think it is (but rather defaults to `0`).

Comment: Show the get function, this seems to be where it might go wrong. As @Bergi mentioned, are you sure you didn't want to show the code here with a backtick (eg `)

Comment: I am working on spring mvc. I use the $ sign to access the phone attribute that I passed via the controller action. Is there any other way I can access this? Not that the above code is a part of the script tag in my JSP page

Comment: You really should drop the JavaScript completely (remove the `<script>` tag) and just use a serverside loop. Notice that `document.write` is totally deprecated. Even if you'd get this working, it's the wrong approach.

Comment: If you want (need) to do this in JavaScript nonetheless, just serialise your `phone.userList` into a JSON array, output that into the script like an array literal, and use a simple js loop over that array.

Comment: @Bergi, You are the real MVP ! :D
I used JSP forEach loop and removed the script tag. 
Thank you for letting me know.

Answer (score 0):

As @Bergi suggested, 
It is a bad practise to use script tag in JSP pages. 
I instead used JSP forEach loop and it worked.

Code:

```
<c:forEach items="${phone.userList}" var="phoneuserobj">
        <tr>
            <td>${phoneuserobj.id}</td>
            <td>${phoneuserobj.firstname}</td>
        </tr>
    </c:forEach>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for( var counter = 0; counter < userlistlength ; counter++){
            console.log("Counter "+counter); //prints 0 and 1
            id = '${phone.userList.get(counter+1).id}';
            firstname = '${phone.userList.get(counter+1).firstname}';
            document.write("{"+id+","+firstname+"}\n");
            document.write("\n");
        }
```

Comment: www.nexttutorial.com